# Save files in Blobs or Base64 string to database

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Using Node.js server and **MongoDB** I want to store **images, videos, and audios** in Database. ok?

I know we can store files in the document as a **blob** or as a **base64** string.

As I need to send the files (images, videos, and audios) as base64 string data to server I don't know which approach should I follow:

> 1. Send base64 data to server ==> Convert it to Blob ==> Save the Blob
>    to database
> 2. Send base64 data to server ==> Just save the base64 data to
>    database

Please help , I don't know if saving files as base64 data could cause any issues... because each document has limit of 16MB ...

Comment: I think you need [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/). With videos or audio files you easily get more than 16MiB

Comment: You can store media data within the document (if under the limit of 16 MB) as type "binData" (or binary data); see [available types](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#available-types). If larger size, use MongoDB GridFS.